# I am trying to print cyrillic charaters on a adafruit thermal printer but csnt seem to figure how

Tags: arduino-uno, thermal-printer, cyrillic

I am using Arduino uno board with a Adafruit thermal printer with the Adafruit_Thermal.h library and have set the code page to the Cyrillic characters but I can only print one character at a time using the write func and entering the ASCII value as a parameter. How can i print longer messages at a time.

I am using this code and when i run it, it dumps all the characters in the table including the Cyrillic ones, so i know that the printer supports them

```
#include <Adafruit_Thermal.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(5,6);
Adafruit_Thermal printer(&mySerial);

void setup() {
  
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

pinMode(7, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(7, LOW);
mySerial.begin(9600);
printer.begin();
printer.setCodePage(CODEPAGE_MIK);
dump();

}

void dump() {
  uint8_t major, minor, c;

  printer.println(F("        01234567  89ABCDEF"));
  for(major=0; major<16; major++) {
    printer.print(F("     "));
    printer.print(major, HEX);
    printer.print(F("- "));
    for(minor=0; minor<16; minor++) {
      c = (major << 4) | minor;
      if(c < 32) c = ' '; // Skip control codes!
      printer.write(c);
      if(minor == 7) printer.print(F("  "));
    }
    printer.println();
  }
}
void loop() {

   
   }
```